# What is a difference between "too adj to do" VS "so adj that ..."?

Tags: grammar

> The mailman was too lazy to **finish his route everyday.**

Focused on a Action (**couldn't finish his route everyday**)

> The mailman was so **lazy** that he couldn't finish his route everyday.

Focused on a State (**lazy**)

I've know the first sentence is focused on a result, and the second sentence is focused on a state.

Is it right that I've known the difference?